# Fast way to compute distance matrix in R for large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

I am working on R to compute the distance matrix for a large matrix. Matrix has 39900 rows and 1990 columns:

```
set.seed(123)
#Matrix
M <- matrix(rnorm(39900*1990),nrow = 39900,ncol = 1990)
```

The issue appears when I want to compute the distance matrix:

```
#Distance
d <- dist(M,method = 'euclidean')
```

Having a computer with icore3 processor and 8GB ram using R 64 bits, it has elapsed more than 24 hours and the matrix has not been computed yet.

Is there any way to boost the computing maybe using `Rcpp` or other method? I need to obtain the distance matrix and other solutions in this site have not contributed to solve the problem.

Comment: @F.Privé Hi many thanks! Unfortunately, that solution is about two matrices, in my case I only have one matrix and I want the distances between all rows!

Comment: Use the same matrix for X and Y?

Comment: @F.Privé Yeah that is valid too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps try the `distances` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/distances/distances.pdf

```
install.packages("distances")
library("distances")
set.seed(123)
M <- matrix(rnorm(39900*1990),nrow = 39900,ncol = 1990)
d <- distances(M)
```

Comment: This worked amazingly! Just curious the resulting object can be fed into a clustering algorithm like `hclust()`?

Comment: From the documentation, you get a `distances` object from calling `distances::distances()`. It looks like you can pass a `distances` object to `distances::distance_matrix()` and get a `dist` object as output, which `hclust` can consume.